# Negative Edge in Graph

Tags: graph, edges

What is the physical significance of negative edges in a graph i.e when we have to put the edges negative in real world programming ?

Answer (score 1):

Negetive edges represent "loss" in real world examples. Now lets take an example:
if you are purchasing an item that has some price. if you are giving money from your side that means you are losing some of your money right? now on the other hand if you sell some of your old books in the market and get some money. now this increases your money count. So, the first case can be considered as a -ve edge weight and the later case can be considered as a +ve edge weight in real life example.